# Can my kid use the pen display while I'm working on my PC?

Tags: graphics-tablet

I'm planning to buy a a graphic tablet (pen display) to motivate my kids to learn using Photoshop. But I have a concern: if I have to decide all the time if I work on the computer or they use the pen display, I afraid it would kill the project (they draw a lot, and I work a lot).

Is that possible to setup a system which lets them using the pen display with Photoshop while I'm working on the same PC?

Comment: Not really. Pen display is basically just a secondary screen and the stylus controls the computer the display is attached to. It's sort of like plugging in 1 more display and 1 more mouse. The display gives you more screen real estate (or mirrors the primary screen) and the two mice (or in this case stylus) moves the same cursor. So the only way I see this happening is if you get a tablet pc... Something like the Cintiq Companion with Windows (pretty expensive). Another device that comes to mind is Microsoft Surface, since those run full Windows as well (except that one model that didn't).

Comment: @Joonas - you know, that could be an answer!  If it was, then I'd upvote it.